# Como dar permissões para todos os usuários do MySQL ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma base de dados que todos os usuários do MySQL devem conseguir acessar. 
Já tentei um `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on nomedobanco.* to '%'@'%' identified by`, mas sem sucesso.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando GRANT do MySQL não aceita wildcard para definição de usuários.

Uma opção mais simples é definir para um host específico e sem especificar um usuário:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nomedobanco.* TO ''@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Nesse caso, qualquer usuário autenticado pelo localhost terá as permissões cedidas.

Outro modo é definir cada um dos usuários:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nomedobanco.* TO 
 'usuario1'@'localhost',
 'usuario2'@'localhost',
 'usuario3'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! No caso o "IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD" eu posso manter a palavra PASSWORD? Cada um dos usuários tem uma senha diferente.

Comment: Não pois a identificação se dá pela senha. Nesse caso todos teriam senhas iguais. Uma opção melhor pode ser a segunda forma.